# how do you refer to more than one "scope and sequence"

Tags: grammatical-number

If you are referencing a collection, is it called Scope and Sequences, Scopes and Sequences, or what would be the rule for the plural form of this phrase?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to give more context. A collection of what?

Answer (score 2):

At least two authorities treat this as a newish compound noun, pluralising in the normal way for lexemes (the addition of an *s*)

(a) the [New South Wales Education Standards Agency](https://educationstandards.nsw.edu.au/wps/portal/nesa/k-10/understanding-the-curriculum/programming/advice-on-scope-and-sequences):

> **Advice on Scope and Sequences**
>
> A scope and sequence is a summary of what is to be taught, the
> sequence in which it will be taught and the syllabus outcomes that may
> be addressed in the intended learning.

...............

(b) [Baldwin High School, Baldwin, NY](https://www.baldwinschools.org/Page/10193) [reformatted]:

> Baldwin High School: Our School
>
> ...
>
> - Course Descriptions
> - IXL Summer Assignments
> - Molloy College High School Scholars Program
> - Photo Gallery
> - Resources
> - Scope and Sequences
> - Students of the Month ...
> - Please see below for BHS Mathematics Department's scope
>   and sequences ....

One can compare the obvious compound noun

- one bus stop, three bus stops.

There are examples of the isoformal

- *trouble and strifes* (Cockney rhyming slang for 'wives')
  and certainly
- a couple of *black and whites* were cruising the neighbourhood (US informal for police cars)

on the internet, showing the same treating of the phrase rather as a single lexeme, a compound noun. Possibly the least controversial example is

> - *bed and breakfast* [plural bed and breakfasts] ...
>
> (2) [count] a guest house that provides bed and breakfast
> accommodation.

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bed-and-breakfast)] [adjusted]